# Setting a row value based on hour value of the index in pandas

Tags: pandas

The indices to my DataFrame are datetimes, one row every 10 minutes. I want to **set** the value of a column based on the hour value of the index. Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep='\t');
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

rng = df.index
day_index = rng[(rng.hour >= 8) & (rng.hour < 22)] 
night_index = rng[(rng.hour > 8 ) & (rng.hour <= 22)]
```

So far so good: the following give the expected parts of the DF:

```
df.loc[day_index].head()

                     LAeq
DateTime                 
2018-01-16 08:00:00  50.0
2018-01-16 08:10:00  49.4
2018-01-16 08:20:00  49.2
2018-01-16 08:30:00  48.9
2018-01-16 08:40:00  48.1
```

and

```
df.loc[night_index].head()

             LAeq
DateTime                 
2018-01-15 23:10:00  42.8
2018-01-15 23:20:00  41.9
2018-01-15 23:30:00  43.5
2018-01-15 23:40:00  45.6
2018-01-15 23:50:00  45.7
```

Shouldn't I be able to **set** a value for a column for these day and night periods, something like:

```
df.loc[day_index, 'Limit'] = 55
df.loc[night_index, 'Limit'] = 45
```

Both give an `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'` What is the simplest way of setting these? I'm making do with the terrible un-Pythonic (warning this code may hurt your eyes):

```
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour

for i in range(len(df.index)):
h = int(df.ix[i]['Hour'])
if (8 <= h < 22):
    df.ix[i, 'Limit'] = 55
else:
    df.ix[i,'Limit'] = 45
```

Which is ugly, but it works.

Comment: It is work on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove filtering and return boolean mask:

```
day_mask = (rng.hour >= 8) & (rng.hour < 22)
night_mask = (rng.hour > 8 ) & (rng.hour <= 22)


df[day_mask].head()
df[night_mask ].head()

#same as
#df.loc[night_mask ].head()
```

---

```
df.loc[day_mask, 'Limit'] = 55
df.loc[night_mask , 'Limit'] = 45
```

Or better:

```
df['limit'] = np.where(day_mask, 55, 45)
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. You guys & gals are starting to scare me with your response times.

Comment: In SO is there a metric / ratio: time taken to formulate a question over the time taken to answer it??

Comment: @djnz0feh - in my opinion it is hard create good question, like say [andy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)